# python : IOError: Label: File 'DroidSans.ttf' not found in linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am using font_name: `Verdana` in `.kv` file. It is working fine in windows but in linux it gives error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/text/__init__.py", line 285, in resolve_font_name
     raise IOError('Label: File %r not found' % fontname)
 IOError: Label: File 'Verdana.ttf' not found
```

Comment: `verdana` isn't installed in Linux by default. You have to install it separately if you want to use it.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/578057/installation-of-fonts-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Do a quick google search. It may differ depending on your Linux distro

Comment: [**To install a system-wide font**](https://serverfault.com/questions/89931/installing-msttcorefonts-on-ubuntu)

Comment: thanks everyone.i downloaded verdana.ttf and copy in /usr/share/fonts/truetype after it problem solved